# Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2008 + "Instance Status Checks failed"

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip, windows-server-2008, cloud, amazon-ebs

I have Windows Server 2008 launched on Amazon EC2 Instance.

While doing some configuration I changed IP address to the private IP address of Amazon EC2 instance.

As soon as I changed IP address, remote connection to the instance got disconnected and after that when I tried to reconnect, I am getting the "Instance Status Checks failed" error.

Can any one help me, how can I get into the instance?

Thanks

Comment: Answer may best be answered on [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @Jeremy, do you have any idea about source where I can find hint of this question

Comment: Perhaps this would be a good place to start: [Troubleshooting Instances with Failed Status Checks](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html).  Good luck!

Comment: @man19688 how you have solved your issue ... i am facing same issue ...any solution worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

terminate and relaunch the instance. Or just restart the instance.